# xsd doesn't work with nullable value

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a problem to validate my XML file with xsd in C# win application.

I have customize my element xsd with `nillable="true"` but doesn't work and gives me error:

> The element 'FLG_SUPERVISOR' is not valid. value '' is not valid for
>   the data type 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:decimal' - The string
>   \" \ "is not a valid Decimal value

my xsd is this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
 <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 

 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="DocumentElement">
  <xs:complexType>
   <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="UserSettings" >
   <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
 <xs:element name="ID_UTENTE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:decimal" />
 <xs:element name="ID_GRUPPO" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:decimal" />
 <xs:element name="NOME_UTENTE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
 <xs:element name="PASSWORD_UTENTE" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
 <xs:element name="FLG_ABILITATO" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
 <xs:element name="DES_UTENTE" type="xs:string" />
 <xs:element name="ACRONIMO" type="xs:string" />
 <xs:element name="FLG_SUPERVISOR" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"
 type="xs:decimal" />
```

I have set `nillable="true"` but if my `FLG_SUPERVISORE` value in xml is blank (null) gives me this error:
How can I change my xsd to enable blank/null value?
(`nillable ="true"` doesn't work in no other element case).

Thanks a lot

Comment: it must be nullable="true" and not nillable="true".

Comment: if i write nullable visual studio gives me error: the nullable attribute is not supported in this context

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the correct attribute name is "nillable".

Secondly, specifying an element as nillable allows you to have an empty instance provided that the instance contains the attribute xsi:nil="true". I suspect that this attribute is missing from your element instance.

Personally, I never use xsi:nil. If you want to allow an element to contain either a decimal, or nothing, there are two ways to do it:

(a) define a type as a union type with two members, one being xs:decimal, the other being a string with a fixed value of "" (the empty string)

(b) define a type as a list type with item type xs:decimal, having minLength=0 and maxLength=1.

Comment: may you post me right code for union of my example <xs:element name="FLG_ABILITATO" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" /> so i change my xsd? thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, if you stop me in the street and ask for directions, I'm prepared to point you in the right direction, but I'm not prepared to hold your hand and walk there with you. That's partly because I don't have time, and partly because I think you will learn more by doing it yourself.